CoreData can't load/create NSPersistentContainer
I'm currently building a project with CoreData (with Apps Group) to share data between my Keyboard Extension and the main app.
I deleted the app on my phone by mistake and since I recompiled it, I always got this error when using the custom keyboard extension:

CoreData: error: <NSPersistentStoreCoordinator: 0x303701ff0>: Attempting recovery from error encountered during addPersistentStore: 0x30120e280 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The file cannot be saved because you do not have authorisation." UserInfo={reason=No permissions to create file; code = 1}
SmartKeyboard/DataController.swift:37: Fatal error: Unresolved error The file cannot be saved because you do not have authorisation., ["reason": No permissions to create file; code = 1].

Here's my code:
class DataController: ObservableObject {
    enum SetScoreMethod {
        case decrement, increment
    }
    
    static var shared = DataController()
    var moc: NSManagedObjectContext
    @Published var game: Game?
    
    private init() {
        
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MODEL_NAME")
        if let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "my.group.identifier")?.appendingPathComponent("MODEL_NAME.sqlite") {
        
            let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url)
            description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
            description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
            description.isReadOnly = false
            
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
            container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
                        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
                    }
                    
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(error.localizedDescription), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
            }
        }

        self.moc = container.viewContext
        fetchOrCreateGame()
    }
    
    func fetchOrCreateGame() -> Void {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Game> = Game.fetchRequest()
        do {
            let results = try self.moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
            if let existingGame = results.first {
                self.game = existingGame
            } else {
                let newGame = Game(context: self.moc)
                newGame.score = 0
                try self.moc.save()
                self.game = newGame
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch or create Game entity: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    public func setScore(_ method: SetScoreMethod,with score: Int) -> Void {
        do {
            if method == .increment {
                self.game!.score += Int16(score)
            }
            
            if method == .decrement {
                if self.game!.score >= score {
                    self.game!.score -= Int16(score)
                }
            }
            
            try self.moc.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to save new score: \(error)")
        }
        
    }
}

I need some explainations to fix this, I don't know much of CoreData

This isn't specifically a Core Data error, it's about file permissions and how iOS sandboxes apps. The error is telling you that your code isn't allowed to create a file in a location. It's showing up in Core Data because your persistent container is trying to create SQL files in that location.
Your url is fine and should work-- if your app group entitlements are set up properly. The error suggests that there's a problem with this. Probably either the app or the keyboard extension doesn't have the right entitlement, or maybe they both have one but they don't match. Both of them must have the same app group entitlement for this to work.

ok, I see what mean, thanks! Both have the same app group entitlement so I don't know but I fixed it changing the data model name
